# RelativeLayout params AddRule doesn't consistently work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've got a view that's a child of a `RelativeLayout`, and I'm trying to modify the layout parameters in the Java. I get the `LayoutParams` as follows:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlp = (LayoutParams) dimBackground.getLayoutParams();

dlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, currentTextView.getId());
//dlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

dimBackground.setLayoutParams(dlp);
```

The line `dlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, currentTextView.getId());` doesn't change the position of the `dimBackground`, but if I uncomment the line below, then `dimBackground` will get aligned the bottom of the parent view.

Any idea why the first rule wouldn't be working?

**Edit:**

As suggested, I tried in the xml, still with no luck. Below is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dim_background_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/product_subtotal_row"
    android:background="@color/gray_tint"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: 2 comments: 1) this line `dimBackground.setLayoutParams(dlp);` is unnecessary, dlp already is the current layout on the background, u don't have to set it again. Try to manually create this layout on XML (just for testing), it's likely that there's some existing rule conflicting with the new one you're adding.

Comment: @Budius : `dimBackground.setLayoutParams(dlp);` will call `requestLayout()` so it is required.

Comment: you call `requestLayout();` =]

Comment: You need to verify if you currentTextView have an Id (even if it's done progamatically or in XML).

Comment: It does have an id(I've verified in code)

Answer (score 2):

(Since you didn't post too much details about your layout... it's difficult to give you a definitive answer).

I guess that your `currentTextView` and your `dimBackground` don't have the same parent relativeLayout.
As mentionned in the [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) doc :

> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent.

So please double check that `currentTextView` and `dimBackground` are both child of the same `RelativeLayout`